Washing machine violently vibrates house's frame
I have a washing machine on the second floor of an 1870 midwestern US house. It was put there by the previous owner. When I tried to use it for the first time, I was surprised by the entire second floor shaking when the machine goes on its spin cycle. It may have been shaking even more, but I do not know because I turned the machine off quickly to prevent further damage to my house. Some research tells me that washing machines need to be in a specially framed laundry room to avoid this issue.
I see three ways to deal with this, and I do not like them for the given reasons:

Hire a framing contractor to frame the upstairs properly for this. I expect that this will be very expensive. Nonetheless, I will ask some contractors.
Never use the spin cycle on the washing machine. I expect that this will make drying a huge pain. I want to be able to move my clothes to the dryer immediately without any air drying steps.
Move the washer (and probably dryer) to the basement. I do not like this option because it is a subdivided home (three apartments, was originally built as single family home) and the basement is not exclusive to my apartment.

Is there any other option?
Also, how concerned should I be about the frame already being damaged? There is a hallway in the area that has a slightly uneven floor. Could nails have been vibrated lose? I will ask the aforementioned framing contractors this as well.

Without seeing some pictures or a sketch of your house, it's hard to say what the fix should be.  But, you could try laying a sheet of something like 3/4" plywood under the washer, spanning as much of the floor as practical.  This will not fix the issue, but may make it more tolerable.

It can also be the washer needs work.  Bad bearing/loose mounts inside can cause shaking also.  I am assuming the machine is level and the clothes/load was evenly placed in the tub.  My washer is just placed on the floor, so no special built was done.

The washing machine should be checked to see if there isn't a balance issue that needs to be corrected in the machine, before condemning the home framing.   Every time I encountered a vibrating washer it was because the washer had an issue, not the room it was in.

To add to RMDman's comment (with which I agree), a correctly-operating washing machine will move very little during its agitating and spin cycles. Putting your hand on the machine will allow you to feel that it is operating, but will be far less than might be required to shake the house. Fix or replace the washing machine before you conclude the house is the problem.

Maybe why the washer/dryer were left behind, might be other reasons, but they are usually not that cheap to leave.

I'll take apart the washer to check for any problems, but I don't think that the machine is to blame because it's a new inverter one that spins really fast. In the rental that I was living in before this there was a similar machine that shook about as much, but it wasn't a problem because it was in the basement.

Also, it's a front load machine so it will never be perfectly balanced I think.

Is there any other option? ... why did you not think of replacing or repairing the washer?
